# Exception type: ThreadAbortException

Tags: wcf, iis

We have WCF service, it works in development environment. When we deploy at production environment, we are facing below error:

```
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/w3svc/1/root/service-1-130039569765206325 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /service 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\service\ 
    Machine name: DELTA 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1320 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: ThreadAbortException 
    Exception message: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
```

Please help us to find a solution for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your IIS is unable to allocate enough memory for the application and the thread is being aborted. Its an IIS configuration issue not your code issue. Try to recreate virtual directory and create an entry.

Comment: We tried the IIS configuration as mentioned in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx, this did not help. our service behavior [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]